# Yahoo Weather WebService

Tags: webservice-client, yql, yahoo-weather-api

I'm trying to find a way to get some weather information with Yahoo Weather using Yahoo Query Language.

As I'm living in France, in a city called Nice, the following query returns an error:

```
select * from weather.forecast where location='Nice'
```

I have the latitude and longitude coordinated, so how can I give them to YQL to return the weather info? Is this service worldwide or just for the US?

Answer (score 4):

You should use another YQL datatable instead. I have tried this query and it works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM weather.bylocation WHERE location='Nice' AND unit="c"
```

[This is the YQL console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20weather.bylocation%20WHERE%20location%3D'Nice'%20AND%20unit%3D%22c%22&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys)

I have added `unit="c"` to get it it Celsius, assuming that you want that. If not, use "f".

Internally the `weather.bylocation` table is using the following two things:

1. Lookup of the 'where on earth identifier (`woeid`) for the location,
2. and then lookup of the weather for this id.

See the internals of that table below:

```
    <execute><![CDATA[
      default xml namespace ='http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/schema.rng'; 
      var x = y.query('select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="'+location+'"');
      var s = x.results;
      var woeid = s..woeid;
      var weather = y.rest('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w='+woeid+'&u='+unit).get().response;
      response.object = <weather>{weather}</weather>;
    ]]></execute>
```

---

Regarding your 2nd question about usage of latitude and longitude coordinated:
I don't know if you can use them but maybe you don't even need this anymore now, right?

Also good read:

http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/concepts.html

Comment: if you want to change unit to Celsius when you use weather.forecast table, you need to add this condition with AND operator: u="c" i.e.: select * from weather.forecast where woeid=823015 and u="c"

Comment: This query no longer works. Getting this error: `Please provide valid credentials`. It appears YQL is becoming less and less reliable as websites either block the user agent or require OAuth.